# RGB To Depth mapping

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I did try to search this kind of problem if someone already faced earlier but I did found If I missed I am sorry.So please guide.

I mapped the RGB to depth frame in ROS but it is not mapped correctly.

Can any one please guide me.
Why its like this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59081/rgb-to-depth-mapping/) by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pep Lluis Negre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4205/pep-lluis-negre/) on 2013-03-24**:
Are you using a stereo camera or some RGBD sensor like kinect?

**Comment by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on 2013-03-25**:
I am using Microsoft Kinect and.....subscribed to the following..../camera/depth/points and /camera/rgb/image_color.....

**Comment by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on 2013-03-25**:
You can use topic "/camera/depth_registered/points"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use topic "/camera/depth_registered/points" and callback function as follows

```
    void callback(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr& msg){
      BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZRGB& pt, msg->points){
         ROS_INFO("\t(%f, %f, %f,%d, %d, %d)\n", pt.x, pt.y, pt.z,pt.r,pt.g,pt.b);
        }
```

in your main you can subscribe as follows

```
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1, callback);
```

Then you can get the points with RGB valuse :)

---

Originally posted by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) with karma: 104 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on 2013-03-25**:
Thanks hiranya for your reply.It really works.My one question regarding the above code.Why "nan" values appear in it.2ndly How I can get the each pixel number to the corresponding information (xyz and rgb), because I am doing Image Identification I need that info also.thanks in advance..

**Comment by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on 2013-03-25**:\

1. The nan values are value points that Kinect cannot capture depth information everywhere such as reflective surface, light-emitting surfaces etc. 2.There are two types of point clouds organized (get the each pixel number to corresponding 3d information)and unorganized.you need an organized one.

**Comment by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on 2013-03-25**:
The above mentioned are organized or unorganized ?How to get the organized point clouds ?

**Comment by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on 2013-03-26**:
yes its organized pcl. WIDTH 640* HEIGHT 480  hope you can get an idea from this http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php about organized PCL.

**Comment by [Muhammad Atif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4210/muhammad-atif/) on 2013-03-28**:
It really works but with one problem.If we cut first 32 pixel then it works very well.I am trying to dig out this problem I did not found but if some one know please share with us."Matching of depth with RGB works when first 32 pixel removed."